# Is it possible to have an if block (not just a statement) in the parameters definition section?

Tags: modelica

I have a model where some parameters are functions of other parameters, which is OK. The particularity is that the formula to be used depend on a choice (another parameter). 
I.e. I have a pipes assembly and starting from some parameters (diameter, pitch and number of pipes), I want to characterise the external flow (hydraulic-diameter, ...). But the "character" depends on the assembly shape (triangular or square in my case).
Here follows a code example:

```
parameter Modelica.SIunits.Diameter Dext=0.11 "Pipe external diameter";
parameter Integer Ntubes=1 "Number of pipes in parallel";
parameter Real P2D=1.3 "Pitch to diameter ratio";

parameter String pattern="square" "Pipes pattern" annotation(choices(choice="square",choice="triangle"));

if pattern=="square" then
  parameter Modelica.SIunits.Area Asub = Dext^2 * (P2D^2 - Modelica.Constants.pi/4) "Subchannel Cross Section Area";
  parameter Integer NtE = integer((Ntubes * Modelica.Constants.pi * Dext^2 / (4 * Asub)) + 0.5) "Number of pipes for same cross area";
  parameter Real hcCorr = Dext*Ntubes/(Dh*NtE) "Heat Exchange Correction";
elseif pattern=="triangle" then
  parameter Modelica.SIunits.Area Asub = Dext^2 * ((P2D^2 * sqrt(3)) - Modelica.Constants.pi/2)/2 "Subchannel Cross Section Area"; //2 (6/3rd) triangles for each pipe
  parameter Integer NtE = integer((Ntubes * Modelica.Constants.pi * Dext^2 / (4 * Asub)) + 0.5) "Number of pipes for same cross area";
  parameter Real hcCorr = Dext*Ntubes/(Dh*NtE) "Heat Exchange Correction";
end if;
parameter Modelica.SIunits.Diameter Dh = sqrt(Asub*Ntubes*4/(Modelica.Constants.pi*NtE)) "hydraulic diameter of external area";
```

I know I could do it parameter by parameter with an "inline" statement as follows:

```
parameter Modelica.SIunits.Area Asub = if pattern=="square" then Dext^2 * (P2D^2 - Modelica.Constants.pi/4) elseif pattern=="triangle" then Dext^2 * ((P2D^2 * sqrt(3)) - Modelica.Constants.pi/2)/2 else 0 "Subchannel Cross Section Area";
```

Since it is always the same condition, I would like to use a single if block (like in the example). However, the syntax is wrong and I do not understand why.
I could also use repleaceble components, but I think that simpler approach (use of 'if') should exist...

Comment: I think the answer boils down to the fact if-statements in the form you are using it, are just allowed in `equation` and `algorithm` sections in Modelica (by the language's specification).

My question regarding your example is: two out of the three equations you are using for the parameters are the same, therefore your second code example is actually the full solution to your problem. I guess the final implementation will have different equations, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If-statements can only occur in algorithms (and equation sections).
There are conditional declarations - but they are so restricted that they cannot be used for this.

However, you can do it in another way, by having the computations in a function - and returning a parameter record.

```
  record Geo
    Modelica.SIunits.Area Asub;
    Integer NtE;
    Real hcCorr;
    Modelica.SIunits.Diameter Dh;
  end Geo;

  function computeGeo
    input String pattern;
    input Modelica.SIunits.Diameter Dext;
    input Integer Ntubes;
    input Real P2D;
    output Geo geo;
  algorithm 
    if pattern=="square" then
      geo.Asub :=Dext^2*(P2D^2 - Modelica.Constants.pi/4)   "Subchannel Cross Section Area";
      geo.NtE :=integer((Ntubes*Modelica.Constants.pi*Dext^2/(4*geo.Asub)) + 0.5)         "Number of pipes for same cross area";
      geo.Dh :=sqrt(geo.Asub*Ntubes*4/(Modelica.Constants.pi*geo.NtE));
      geo.hcCorr :=Dext*Ntubes/(geo.Dh*geo.NtE) "Heat Exchange Correction";
    elseif pattern == "triangle" then
      geo.Asub :=Dext^2*((P2D^2*sqrt(3)) - Modelica.Constants.pi/2)/2     "Subchannel Cross Section Area"; //2 (6/3rd) triangles for each pipe
      geo.NtE :=integer((Ntubes*Modelica.Constants.pi*Dext^2/(4*geo.Asub)) + 0.5)         "Number of pipes for same cross area";
      geo.Dh := sqrt(geo.Asub*Ntubes*4/(Modelica.Constants.pi*geo.NtE));
      geo.hcCorr :=Dext*Ntubes/(geo.Dh*geo.NtE) "Heat Exchange Correction";
    end if;
  end computeGeo;

  parameter Modelica.SIunits.Diameter Dext=0.11 "Pipe external diameter";
  parameter Integer Ntubes=1 "Number of pipes in parallel";
  parameter Real P2D=1.3 "Pitch to diameter ratio";

  parameter String pattern="square" "Pipes pattern" annotation(choices(choice="square",choice="triangle"));
  parameter Geo geo=computeGeo(pattern, Dext, Ntubes, P2D);
```

Assuming the two last statements of the if/else-branches should the same they could be moved after the end. You might also used named parameters for the function call - to reduce the risk of errors.

The downside is that the names are slightly longer, and that you have to manually order the statements in the function due to dependencies.

I would personally also change pattern to an enumeration.

Comment: Even if being able to define if-blocks in the parameter area would be easier, I think the function approach is a nice enough solution. Thanks

Comment: One think not really clear to me is the need to go trough a 'record'. Cannot I define as function outputs the list of parameters I am computing?

Comment: The record is used to group the function outputs together. You can have multiple outputs from a function - but you cannot directly use that for several parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
parameter Boolean bool = true;
parameter Real x = if bool then 1 else 0;
```

With your example for Asub:

```
parameter Modelica.SIunits.Area Asub = if pattern=="square" then EXPR1 elseif pattern=="triangle" then EXPR2 else EXPR3;
```

The whole line for each parameter will get rather long tho.